# Selenide how to find only child of SelenideElement

Tags: java, selenide

I have SelenideElement and want to find specific element - his child, but instead of this, i get child of another element.

On application i have table with i.e. 30 tbody's inside. I iterate on each div and I want to get on each iteration child of specific element. Instead of this i get child of first element.
i.e. 
I have following elements:

```
<table>
 <tbody>Element 1
  <tr>Child
   <td>Child's child 1</td>
   <td>Child's child 2</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>Element 2
  <tr>Child
   <td>Child's child 1</td>
   <td>Child's child 2</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
```

And i want to get text of: Child's child 2 from Element 2
instead of this, i get  Child's child 2 from Element 1

```
SelenideElement element = $x("//table//tbody[2]/tr", i);
element.find(byXpath("//td[2]/div")).getText()
```

Expected result: I get content of element 2, but i get content of element 1..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options to solve it(both will work):

1. Navigate into the child element through `$("tbody:nth-child(2)").find(By.cssSelector("tr"));`
2. Use `.get()` function: `$$("tbody").get(1).find(By.cssSelector("tr")).getText();`

Get function is designed to navigate in collection elements. So if you have 10 tbody's, you can easily navigate through any of them without specifying it in a selector.